# In a scala spark job, running in yarn, how can I fail the job so that yarn shows a Failed status

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a simple if statement in my scala spark job code, that if false i want to stop the job and mark it failed. I want the yarn UI to show the spark job with a status of failed, but everything i've done so far has stopped the job, but only shows up as successfully finished on the yarn UI.

```
    if(someBoolen) {
        //context.clearAllJobs()
        //System.exit(-1)
        //etc, nothing so far, stops the job and show as failed in the yarn UI
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you just `throw new IllegalStateException("bad karma, abort now");`?

Answer (score 5):

Throwing an exception (and not catching it) will cause the process to fail.

```
if(someBoolen) {
    throw new Exception("Job failed");
}
```

Comment: Maybe i'm submitting incorrectly to yarn, but even if an exception is thrown and the spark job fails, yarn shows the job succeeded

Comment: @JediKid Are you sure you aren't catching it anywhere, maybe to log it in your main or something?

Comment: So after playing around I found that it might be the way I am submitting the job via spark-submit. If I deploy with --deploy-mode cluster, yarn will now show the job as failed, but without the --deploy-mode set, it will always say the job was successful even when it fails.

Comment: By using the Spark-submit you submitting a Spark application, which run all jobs inside the application. Spark application status in Yarn is just FINISHED not depending on was there failed jobs or not. Yarn UI will show only applications, where whole spark driver is failed, or lost. For failed spark Jobs you can check the Spark UI or Spark History Server if configured. Or monitor a Job status from with in the Spark application.